# I am not able to rotate the table based on condition

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform

I want to rotate my table 180 degrees.i wrote a css to work,but its not working.
Here is the code

```
function rotateTable()
{
 table.className="tablecss";
}


<style type="text/css">
        .tablecss
        {       
         transform:rotate(180deg);
        }
</style>
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/transforms2d

Comment: What's the error?  You don't define the variable `table` anywhere we can see.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following too:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
-o-transform: rotate(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
```

And you'll get output as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/YmS4E/embedded/result/).

Comment: Please provide your HTML too in that case.

Comment: i got it...but the value in the table also rotating,how can i do it so that the value in the table should not effect